# accessing specific elements in custom loss function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

When defining a custom loss function for a classification problem, is there a way to access particular elements of y_true and y_pred?

Use-case: multi-label classification problem where I wanna penalize the model extra if I predict a false positive for class 5 i.e. `y_true[5] == 0` but  `y_pred[5] == 1`

I'm defining the loss like:

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
      wt = 10 if (y_true[5]==0 and y_pred[5]==1) else 1
      return wt * binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

I also tried to check if `K.gather(y_true, 5) == 0` but that doesn't seem to do it.

My batch size is > 1 (256) and i'm using `fit_generator` - if that makes any difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to access particular elements of y_true and y_pred?

The indexing of Keras tensors works similarly to the indexing of numpy arrays. The only difference is that the result is a Keras tensor. Therefore, you should use Keras operations subsequently.

---

**Possible implementation of your loss function**

For example, here is how your loss function might be implemented:

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    a = K.equal(y_true[:, 5], 0)
    b = K.greater(y_pred[:, 5], 0.5)
    condition = K.cast(a, 'float') * K.cast(b, 'float')
    wt = 10 * condition + (1 - condition)
    return K.mean(wt[:, None] * K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
```

**NOTE:** Not tested.